# submenu bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, submenu

Se alguém poder me ajudar estou tentando criar um sub-menu de preferência que abra para a direita dentro de administrativo abre-se acesso, funcionários e painel de controle dentro de acesso teria dois sub menus cadastrar acesso e listar acesso, segue o código.

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Administrativo</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Acesso</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="administrativo.php?link=2">Cadastrar Acesso</a></li>
                <li><a href="administrativo.php?link=3">Listar Acesso</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Funcionários</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Painel de Controle</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução conforme sua ajuda paulo, encontrei o código abaixo e fiz as alterações para me atender.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       
<div class="container">
  <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
  <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
  <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se quiser deixar mais interessante, use a função animate da biblioteca Jquery

Segue o código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>


    </title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function abreSubMenu()
                                {
                                    window.document.getElementById("sub-menu").innerHTML = '<ul><li>sub opção 1</li><li>sub opção 2</li><li>sub opção 3</li></ul>' ;

                                }       
        </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="menu">
<ul>
    <li>opção 1</li>
    <li>opção 2</li>
    <li id="sub-menu" onclick="abreSubMenu()">opção 3</li>

</ul>




</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda paulo, mas queria fazer algo mais simples mesmo so nao entendi pq nao esta funcionando o submenu

Comment: Raramente é o código 'alvo'!
Geralmente é alguma alteração acidental em outra parte do projeto.

Answer (score 0):

Raramente é o código 'alvo'!
Geralmente é alguma alteração acidental em outra parte do projeto. Então só com esse código que passou provavelmente não vamos descobrir.
Você pode forçar o menu a abrir com javascript, ou pode debugar até encontrar a alteração. Eu não faço nenhuma das duas coisas. Eu pego o exemplo oficial (do menu drop down abrindo) e vou customizando até encontrar o problema, comparando com meu código problemático. 
Trabalho espartano! Copiar, Colar, voltar, atualizar, etc. Use o sublime text para editar o código.

Comment: vou fazer isso.